# Checking if a char is a digit

Tags: sml, smlnj

As part of a practice SML exam I was asked to write a function that checks if a character 'c' is a digit or not.

I was looking into the `Char.ord` function but it returns the ASCII code and not the integer itself in the character, and I can't seem to check the type.

I looked around it said to use a `datatype wrapper`, but when implementing this into a function; i didn't get the desired result.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the ASCII code you get. If it is a digit, it will be between a range of values (48 - 57 I think). Check the number you get with the number's code in the table.

Here is an example function:

```
fun check x = (ord x > 47) andalso (ord x < 58);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use comparison operators:

```
fun is_digit c = #"0" <= c andalso c <= #"9";
```

On edit: I'm not 100% sure what you meant by using a `datatype wrapper`, but you could also do the following. Convert the char to a string using `str` and then use `Int.fromString` to try to convert to an int. This returns an `int option`. You can then use pattern matching on the return value:

```
fun is_digit c =
    case Int.fromString (str c) of
        NONE => false
        | _ =>true;
```